# If you have multiple dynamic blocks with a post loop on a page, how do you avoid duplicates from inside the render_callback function?

Tags: block-editor

I'm building dynamic blocks to customize the blog index into more of a magazine style layout, featured posts, categories, other content, all mixed together. My dynamic blocks are able to render a loop and post content just fine, but I cannot pass a list of IDs from the render_callback block function to itself when it displays multiple times on the same page, leading to duplicate posts in this block when used in various places on a page.

If you have multiple dynamic blocks rendering a get_posts loop, how do you pass a list of IDs to the next instance to avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP I recall these ways

1. [Static variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static)
2. [Class properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)
3. Databases, Files, Memory (might be flushed though)

to preserve a state, in a hook's callback, that is called multiple times in WordPress and in the order I would consider using myself but it depends on the context (eg WP transients, that store data that expires, can use memory for speedy recalling and database as a fallback).

Global variables might also be listed at the bottom (usually not recommended) and closure tricks closer to the top.

Comment: Thanks, Static worked like a charm. I initially tried a 'Global' variable, that I set, then unset before and after a page loop, but everything I read said not to do this. A static variable persists across loops, but not page requests. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @Noltedesign